$G$ paratopological group and order of elements bounded implies $G$ is topological group
Let $G$ paratopological group. Suppose exits $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $o(g) \leq n$ for all $g \in G$. Prove $G$ is topological group.
I need to prove inverse is continuous, let $U$ a neighborhood of $x^{-1}$, I need to prove exists $V$ neighborhood of $x$ such that $V^{-1} \subset U$.
What I tried is, we see $f: G \rightarrow G$, $f(g)=g ^{n} $ is continuous but i can't find a relationship with this function and inverse, could you help me?

Hint: $x^{-1}=x^{n!-1}.$

Did You want to say, $x^{n-1}$?

No, because we don't know every element has order $n,$ only that each element has order $\leq n.$ @PSW

So is it true that for a $V$ neighborhood of $x$ then $V^{n!-1}=V^{-1}$?

I said it was a hint, not an answer.

I'd suggest $V^k$ is ambiguous - it could mean the image of $V$ under the map $v\mapsto v^k,$ or it could mean ${v_1v_2\cdots v_k\mid v_i\in V}.$

Thanks I see how can I use it.

I'm not even sure this will works, unless the topology is Hausdorff.

@PSW I wouldn't go to the definition, try to use (or prove) the fact that product of continuous functions is continuous.

Thanks both. Now I have an idea to prove it.
